# Django. Регулярное выражение возвращает не корректный вид запроса

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, django, django-rest-framework

Изучаю Django по книге Эрика Мэтиза "Изучаем Python"
При указании URLs используется регулярное выражение

```
path('^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
```

И в строке браузера должно отражаться

```
http://localhost:8000/topics/1
```

А имеем по факту

```
http://localhost:8000/%5Etopics/(%3FP1%5Cd+)
```

В чем проблема? Сам код работает нормально,страницы и данные отражаются правильно.

Comment: Вы уверены, что в книге написано именно path, а не url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

path не для регулярных выражений. Попробуй заменить на

```
path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
```

А для регулярок
`re_path(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),`

Видимо разные версии с автором используете. Раньше (до 2.0) пути прописывались только через регулярные выражения.
Хотя там была функция `url`, а не `path`.